# Command line program to test DHCP service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp

Is there a simple ping-like command to test whether a DHCP service is running on a network? ...on Linux

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even if you don't use a Nagios monitoring server, you can grep the [check_dhcp](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_dhcp) binary or compile it from source and use the check to test a DHCP-Server. E.g.

```
./check_dhcp -v -s <dhcp_server_address> -r <expected_ip_address> -m <mac_address_touse>
```

Answer (score 120):

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1114078/53547), assuming you have installed nmap (`sudo apt install nmap`):

```
sudo nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover
```

Add the `-e $interface` option if you have more than one network interface. (For example: `nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover -e eth0`)

Sample output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-09-27 17:40 CEST
Pre-scan script results:
| broadcast-dhcp-discover: 
|   Response 1 of 1: 
|     IP Offered: 192.168.81.94
|     DHCP Message Type: DHCPOFFER
|     Server Identifier: 192.168.81.2
|     IP Address Lease Time: 5m00s
|     Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
|     Router: 192.168.81.2
|     Domain Name Server: 192.168.81.2
|     Domain Name: example.lan
|     NTP Servers: 192.168.81.10, 192.168.81.2
|     NetBIOS Name Server: 192.168.81.10
|_    NetBIOS Node Type: 8
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.66 seconds
```

Or this output on a different network, with nmap v. 6 :

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-09-27 17:42 CEST
Pre-scan script results:
| broadcast-dhcp-discover: 
|   IP Offered: 192.168.4.101
|   DHCP Message Type: DHCPOFFER
|   Server Identifier: 192.168.4.1
|   IP Address Lease Time: 7 days, 0:00:00
|   Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
|   Time Offset: 7200
|   Router: 192.168.4.1
|   Domain Name Server: 208.91.112.53, 208.91.112.52
|   Renewal Time Value: 3 days, 12:00:00
|_  Rebinding Time Value: 6 days, 3:00:00
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.15 seconds
```

Comment: this didn't find my DHCP server.- must be something wrong with my pc... ethernet works, just not that.

Comment: Note that [this script](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/scripts/broadcast-dhcp-discover.nse) uses a fixed MAC address (`DE:AD:CO:DE:CA:FE`) and therefore will not work if your DHCP server is configured with a whitelist.

Comment: @Bob An option has been added. `--script-args mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`. It hasn't been released yet though.

Comment: For DHCPv6 there's `sudo nmap -6 --script broadcast-dhcp6-discover`

Answer (score 17):

or you can try `dhcpcd` in test mode:

```
dhcpcd -T eth0
```

Comment: Use `dhcpcd -T eth0 -t 2` to timeout after 2 seconds

Comment: Could you please expand on why should this command detect DHCP servers on your network and what kind of output should we expect when someone will be detected?

Comment: a dhcp server needs to see a packet on the network from a host requesting a dhcp configuration message.
therefore we need to mimic a dhcp request,, and this tool will do that and print the response, which will be an ip address, netwmask, default router, and optionally dns resolvers, ntp servers etc.

Comment: not all distros seem to have the dhcpcd program, so you'll have to try the dhclient program in test mode, as discussed elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 14):

[`dhcpdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dhcpdump) is good for sniffing and displaying DHCP packets on the network.

E.g.

```
# dhcpdump -i eth0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TIME: 2015-11-27 11:41:37.379
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (0:11:b9:5:0:b8) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: abce9327
  SECS: 0
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 00:11:b9:05:00:b8:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576
OPTION:  55 (  4) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
                          3 (Routers)
                         28 (Broadcast address)
                          6 (DNS server)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can use it in conjunction with another tool to do DHCP requests, or just use it to watch PCs/devices query DHCP.

Comment: Also available for macOS thru `brew install dhcpdump`.

Comment: This seems to only only work if there is actual dhcp traffic on the network.

Comment: @KenSharp Why? Yes. dhcpdump will only show something when a client on the network requests a dhcp address. If you don't want to wait and don't want to send a dhcp request yourself but only see which machine would answer what IF there were a request, then this is not the solution.

Comment: This is what I'd recommend for anyone trying to diagnose TFTP problems. Knowing the thin client wasn't even requesting the field my router UI exposes as "TFTP Server IP/hostname" and just assumes the DHCP and TFTP will be on the same box would have saved me an entire afternoon.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just make a DHCP request?

```
dhclient
```

For verbose output use:

dhclient -v

Comment: Probably because that will make your system *use* the IP assigned by the DHCP server which is not what one wants when e.g. trying to find out if there are rogue DHCP servers in his network.

Comment: -n option helps here?

Comment: Option `-n` seems to be broken on ISC DHCP Client v4.2.4 on Ubuntu 14 LTS?

Comment: I don't think `-n` does what you think it does.

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=dhclient+-n: "Do not configure any interfaces.  This is most likely to be useful in combination with the -w flag."

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a DHCP test client program a while ago, works on Windows and POSIX:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/dhcptest

Comment: Written in D... It seems possible (with `ldc2`) to get static binaries with `ldc2 -link-defaultlib-shared=false -static -L=-lphobos2-ldc -L=-lz dhcptest.d`

Answer (score 5):

There is a program called dhcping (with just one p)

Answer (score 0):

if you use nagios you could monitor it with [check_dhcp](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_dhcp)

Answer (score 0):

On Debian-Ubuntu systems:

```
dhcpd -f
```

gives good feedback and tests the configuration.

On RH systems try:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/dhcpd configtest
```

Comment: That test is run on the dhcp server to check its configuration, it doesn't tell you if a device on the network will actually see a working server