# How do I find the name of the DHCP server when I have a statically assigned IP address in a Windows environment?

Tags: windows, dhcp, dhcp-server

I work in an environment where we sometimes only have access to the servers and we always set up servers with static IPs.  When I run our reports I need to check DHCP IP ranges and sometimes our documentation does not list the functions of all 12+ servers for a particular client.  Normally we put them on the DC but not always.

How do I determine which server is acting as a DHCP server without logging into them all?  Is there a simple command I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/q/171744/209089

Comment: Port scan the subnet looking for port 67/68 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line program to test DHCP service](https://serverfault.com/questions/171744/command-line-program-to-test-dhcp-service)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I'm not using Linux.  Please give answers for a Windows environment.  Added the Windows tag and updated question to be more clear.

Comment: Are you trying to find "the DHCP server" or "the servers with DHCP 
assigned addresses"?

Comment: Name or IP of the DHCP server on the same network as the statically addressed server I'm on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a simple command.  I hope someone else can come up with something easier.
However, a coworker working on automating these reports wrote a PS command that seems to work:

```
$searchbase = " **distinguishedName** "
Get-ADObject -SearchBase $searchbase -Filter "objectclass -eq 'dhcpclass' -AND Name -ne 'dhcproot'"
```

distinguishedName can be found in the attribute editor for the root (tree?) entry in AD.

Example: DomainName.local

```
$searchbase = "cn=configuration,DC=DomainName,DC=local"
```

It searches AD for an object with a DHCP class.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you don't just run wireshark and filter for DHCP traffic?

Comment: That would require installing software which we don't want to do on other people's servers.