# How can I check my PXE-server configuration

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, netboot

Is it possible to check the things the dhcp-server delivers?

When I configure my dhcp-server I tell it what file to boot from, ex: `pxelinux.0`, and where it should find it, ex: `192.168.0.112`.

Could I verify that this is whats delivered from the dhcp-server somehow without having to actually netboot a machine? I think I'm searching for a some commandline trick here, something like:

I have read this https://serverfault.com/a/875791/243665 but it does not tell me everything. The bootfile name is shown, but the location of the pxeserver (`192.168.0.112`) is missing. Ex:

```
$ sudo nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-12-02 08:49 CET
Pre-scan script results:
| broadcast-dhcp-discover: 
|   Response 1 of 1: 
|     IP Offered: 192.168.0.36
|     DHCP Message Type: DHCPOFFER
|     Server Identifier: 192.168.0.1
|     IP Address Lease Time: 5m00s
|     Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
|     Router: 192.168.0.1
|     Domain Name Server: 192.168.100.10, 192.168.100.11
|     Domain Name: ulfexample.com
|     Renewal Time Value: 2m30s
|     Rebinding Time Value: 4m22s
|_    Bootfile Name: /pxelinux.0
```

Comment: Can you add the response you get from the DHCP server? It should contain the data you need to download pxelinux.

Comment: i neither see here yozr configuration nor logs sofar for me currently for anybody missing needed Informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover
```

uses the script `broadcast-dhcp-discover` found here:

https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/scripts/broadcast-dhcp-discover.nse

you should replace:

```
result_table["IP Offered"] = r.yiaddr_str
```

with:

```
result_table["IP Offered"] = r.yiaddr_str
result_table["IP TFTP Server"] = r.siaddr_str
```

Alternatively you could also use

```
$ sudo nmap --script dhcp-discover
```

the script is:

https://svn.nmap.org/nmap-exp/patrik/nmap-brute/scripts/dhcp-discover.nse

you should replace:

```
table.insert(response, string.format("IP Offered: %s", result.yiaddr_str))
```

with:

```
table.insert(response, string.format("IP Offered: %s", result.yiaddr_str))
table.insert(response, string.format("IP TFTP Server: %s", result.siaddr_str))
```

in both cases you should be able to get the PXE info if the NBP is stored in the `file` field of the DHCP offer and the TFTP server IP is stored in the `siaddr` field of the DHCP offer